# image problems with regular expressions

Tags: php, html, image

When I run the following script, the image is not rendered well. What is the problem here? This is the code:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $url = "http://www.asaphshop.nl/epages/asaphnl.sf/nl_NL/
            ObjectPath=/Shops/asaphnl/Products/80203122";
    $htmlcode = file_get_contents($url);
    $pattern = "/class=\"noscript\"\>(.*)\<\/div\>/isU";
    preg_match_all($pattern, $htmlcode, $matches);
    //print_r ($matches);
    $image = ($matches[0][0]);
    print_r ($image);
?>
```

This is the part of the link I need to copy (the data-src-l part):

```
<div id="ProductImages" class="noscript">
    <ul>  
        <li>
            <a href="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg">
            <img itemprop="image" alt="Jesus Remember Me - Taize Songs (2CD)"
                 src="/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/
                     D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg"
                 data-src-xs="/WebRoot/AsaphNL/Shops/asaphnl/5422/8F43/62EE/
                     D698/EF8E/4DEB/AED5/3B0E/80203122_xs.jpg"
                 data-src-s="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_s.jpg"
                 data-src-m="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122_m.jpg"
                 data-src-l="/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg"
            />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php, not a regexp.

Comment: it's an assignment from my school...
i need to do it with regexp

Comment: Try this `#class=\"noscript\">.*data-src-l=([\"'])(?<url>.*)\1.*</div>#isU`.

Comment: now is this the output: Array ( )... an empty array?!?

Comment: Fixed it, forgot how backreference is noted in PHP (I'm using too many languages) - look here http://regex101.com/r/zE0eQ6/1

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'noscript' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper2.php on line 5
that's the line of: $pattern = "/class="noscript">.*data-src-l=(["'])(?<url>.*)\1.*<\/div>/isU";

Comment: Did you write it as `$pattern = "#class=\"noscript\">.*data-src-l=([\"'])(?<url>.*)\1.*</div>#isU";`? `that's the line` because you did not escape `"`

Comment: no, sorry im a newbe
but now the array is empty again

Comment: Ok, this works `$pattern = "#class=\"noscript\">.*data-src-l=([\"'])(?<url>.*)\\1.*</div>#isU";` Again, the problem that I did not remember the backreference notation. `?<url>` can be removed as it done just for the named capture as I prefer.

Comment: output: Array ( [0] => /WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg )

Comment: So, is it the one that you expect? Just prepend `http://localhost` to it.

Comment: no i need the image itself, not the link

Comment: But you wrote differently in the question, just mentioning the value of the attribute. Show in the question what exactly do you need. Everything from `<img` to `/>` ? or `src` of the image?

Comment: what i need is that the image shows on my screen, but like you see the link is not complete. but i need to make a regular expression for more things than only this image. am i clear like this? it doesn't need to copy the link but the image. it also need to make the link complete.

Comment: `$pattern = '#class="noscript">.*(<img.*>).*</div>#isU';` you should state it clearly, without the details like `the data-src-l part`. The regexp written previously gives you exactly `data-src-l`, but if you need just an image - use regexp in this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern = "#class=\"noscript\">.*data-src-l=([\"'])(?<url>.*)\\1.*</div>#isU";
```

But it is better to deal with the page as with the DOM structure, not as a string. `\\1` is a backreference to `([\"'])` so that the same quotes are used at the end of the string. Not so necessary for the URLs as there should be no direct quotes (unescaped) in them, but it is good for general purpose.

ps: if you need everything between `<img` and `/>` (including them) - `$pattern = '#class="noscript">.*(<img.*>).*</div>#isU';`

Comment: still doesn't work though... i need the whole link like: http://www.asaphshop.nl/WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg but it only gives the part after the imporant piece it only displays: WebRoot/products/8020/80203122/bilder/80203122.jpg

Comment: What the problem to take it from array and prepend whatever you want to it? Do you see `http://asaphshop.nl` in html code of the part under interest? No? Then, obviously, it would not appear in the results of the regexp.

Comment: but how do i fix this then?

Comment: @bananaman take the results of regexp capture, assign it to variable and prepend the required hostname and protocol `$var = 'http://asaphshop.nl' . $matches[correspoding index];`

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMDocument *(I hope that your schoolmistress will not scold you)*:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.asaphshop.nl/epages/asaphnl.sf/nl_NL/?ObjectPath=/Shops/asaphnl/Products/80203122');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$url = $xpath->query('//div[@id="ProductImages"]/ul/li/a/img/@data-src-l')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $url;
```